# Access - Save inputbox value to datasheet (table)

Tags: ms-access, vba, inputbox

I'm stuck on a problem I've tried several outcomes I've found on the Internet but I can't seem to get it working.

```
'Pop-up for information where the pv is located and save it to the db
Private Sub Destroyed_pv_Click()
If Me.Destroyed_pv = vbTrue Then
    Dim Strg As String, hyperlink_pv_var$
    Strg = "Typ your location here..."
    Strg = InputBox("Fill in the location of the PV.", "PV Location", Strg)
    If Strg = "" Then
        hyperlink_pv_var$ = "You didn't fill in the box"
    Else
        hyperlink_pv_var$ = "Location of the PV is: " &vbNewLine & Strg
    End If
    MsgBox hyperlink_pv_var$
Else
End If
End Sub
```

I need to put the outcome of hyperlink_pv_var$ in my datasheet (table)
I've tried this

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Registratie formulier.PV_Location"_&"(PV_Location) VALUES "_&"(hyperlink_pv_var$);"
```

But this doesn't work. I hope you guys can help me out with this.

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Registratie formulier].[PV_Location] " _
    & "(PV_Location) VALUES " _
    & "('" & hyperlink_pv_var$ & "');"
```

Notes:

1. If a field, table or database name contains a blank, enclose in `[ ]`
2. This code assumes that `hyperlink_pv_var$` is always a string.